# Are Microsoft Office ISO/MSI (Non C2R) periodic updates "Cumulative Rollups" just like Windows?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-update, updates, service-pack, software-update

> ## Latest updates for versions of Office that use Windows Installer (MSI)
>
> 04/15/2020 - 2 minutes to read
>
> Use the links on this page to get more information about and download the most recent updates for the perpetual versions of Office 2016, Office 2013, and Office 2010.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/office-updates-msi

- Are these "monthly" Office Updates **"Cumulative" i.e. cover previous patches/ updates?**
- As is the case now with **Windows Monthly Rollups** (Security & Non Security versions).

**Note:** Red marked areas below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these updates for MSI versions of Office are cumulative.

If clicking [KB4549670](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4549670), you will see the list of Office updates released (Microsoft Office 2016, Microsoft Office 2013 and other programs which use MSI) in April 2020.

When you choose one link to open, such as the first one for Access 2016, [KB4484167](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484167/security-update-for-access-2016-april-14-2020), there would be a description of **Security update replacement information**.

[image]

So you just need to install only the most recent updates if needed.